# How to do a check in Node-postgres if something exist in a relation between 2 tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In my Node API I'm building a class to insert some data to DB and I need to check if I'm not adding twice the same values. The data is to be added in 2 tables.

What I have to check is that a `memeberId` related to a `originType` does not exist.
The rule is one member per originType.

The `originType` is like `DOCUMENT` or `CONSENTEE` and I can have:

```
memberID = 1 -> originType = DOCUMENT
memberID = 1 -> originType = CONSENTEE
```

I cannot have the same memberId having the same originType twice

```
memberID = 1 -> originType = DOCUMENT -> wrong
memberID = 1 -> originType = DOCUMENT -> wrong
```

I tried to use `COUNT` but I was not successful as practically I'm not counting from 2 tables and I don't know the best way to make this check.
Right now my code just blocks adding a member because is counting only from `member` table as I believe but I don't know how to make the count from also `conversation` table

The code I have been trying

```
const { originId, memberId, memberType, name, originType } = input;

      const existingConversation = await conversation.selectFirst({
        originId,
        originType,
      });

      if (existingConversation) {
        const existingMember = await member.count({
          memberId,
          originType,
        });

        console.log(existingMember);

        if (existingMember >= 1) {
          return existingConversation;
        }

        await member.insert({
          conversationId: existingConversation.id,
          memberId,
          memberType,
          name,
        });

        return existingConversation;
      }

      const createdConversation = await conversation.insert({
        ...input,
      });

      if (isEmpty(createdConversation)) {
        throw new ApolloError('Error while Adding new conversation!');
      }

      await member.insert({
        conversationId: createdConversation.id,
        memberId,
        memberType,
        name,
      });

      return createdConversation;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I found a solution at least for now.

What I did was to get rid off the count thing and I did a try catch where I check if a member exist for a specific conversation like this

```
const existingConversation = await conversation.selectFirst({
        originId,
        originType,
      });

      if (existingConversation) {
        try {
          const existingMemberPerDocument = await member.selectFirst({
            memberId,
          });

          if (!isEmpty(existingMemberPerDocument)) {
            await conversation.selectFirst({
              conversationId: existingConversation.conversationId,
              originType: existingConversation.originType,
            });

            return existingConversation;
          }

          await member.insert({
            conversationId: existingConversation.id,
            memberId,
            memberType,
            name,
          });

          return existingMemberPerDocument;
        } catch (error) {
          throw new ApolloError('Error while Adding new conversation!', error);
        }
      }
```